# How was this factoring of $1-2x-x^2$ achieved?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring, partial-fractions

If I factor $1-2x-x^2$ using the quadratic formula I get
$$x=\frac{2\pm \sqrt{4-4(-1)(1)}}{2(-1)}$$
$$x=\frac{2\pm \sqrt{8}}{-2}$$
$$x=-1 \pm \sqrt{2}$$

Let $\alpha = -1 +\sqrt{2}$ and $\beta=-1-\sqrt{2}$.

So $1-2x-x^2=-(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)$.

In the image below, where did $1-\alpha x$ and $1-\beta x$ come from?

---

[image]

Comment: Factoring and then using partial fractions

Comment: There seem to be two questions here.  One is how to find $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and the answer is factoring $1-2x-x^2$ to do partial fractions.  You have some answers to that.  The other is why the author went through all this as opposed to using the quadratic formula. I have no clue for this, it may be in some of the preceding text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that: $\frac{1+x}{1-2x-x^2}=\frac{-(1+x)}{(\alpha-x)(\beta-x)}$ with $\alpha$ and $\beta$ as you have them in your quadratic formula part. Using partial fractions, we then get: $$=\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{\alpha-x}+\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{\beta-x}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{1}{\alpha}(1-\alpha x)}+\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{1}{\beta}(1-\beta x)}$$ Then simplifying yields what you want.

Comment: Are you missing a $+x$ after the first $=$?

Comment: @AlJebr Yes indeed. I've added it in now.

Comment: I don't get $1-2x-x^2 = (\alpha-x)(\beta -x)$. We would get a $+x^2$ term on RHS.

Comment: Note also that what they call $\alpha$ is what you would call $-\beta$, and what they call $\beta$, you would call $-\alpha$, in case you were wondering where the minus signs go.

Comment: Your $\alpha$ and your $\beta$ are slightly different from theirs. In my answer, I use yours (obtained from the quadratic formula). See my above comment.

Comment: We would still get a positive $x^2$ term on RHS though

Comment: Sorry, it's fixed by moving a $-1$ to the numerator.

Answer (score 0):

That's an awful lot of work for such a simple factoring problem.
Take out a negative: $$-[x^2+2x-1]$$
Then complete the square inside: $$-[(x+1)^2-2]$$
Use the difference of two squares (Of course $2$ is a square...) $$-(x+1+\sqrt{2})(x+1-\sqrt{2})$$
Is this sufficient?

Comment: I'm not asking how to factor it simply. I am asking where did the factoring in the image I posted come from.

Comment: They used partial fractions

Comment: You can also use my factors for partial fractions, it will come out to be the same. Note that in your image they did not use the quadratic formula, and neither did I. It is a quadratic expression, not an equation...

Answer (score 0):

The author is using a standard technique for solving [linear homogeneous recurrence relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Structure_of_a_homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients) in reverse.  The recurrence $a_n=2a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$ is the one that would generate this polynomial if you assume a solution of the form $a_n=kr^n$ where $r$ is a root of the polynomial. $\alpha$ and $\beta$ come from doing partial fractions on the $f(x)$, so factoring $1-2x-x^2=(1-\alpha x)(1-\beta x)$.  The author doesn't say how they were found, but it was probably by the quadratic formula.  It seems a long way around to conceal the use of the quadratic formula to me. The logic is sound, but it is a long way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Your $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are not the same as the $\alpha$ and $\beta$
in the image you copied.

In the image, they are factoring
$$1−2x−x^2 = -\left(\frac 1\alpha - x\right)\left(\frac 1\beta - x\right).$$
You can confirm that using their values
$\alpha = 1 + \sqrt2$ and $\beta = 1-\sqrt2$,
we have
\begin{align}
\frac 1\alpha &= \frac 1{1 + \sqrt2} = -1+\sqrt2, \\
\frac 1\beta  &= \frac 1{1 - \sqrt2} = -1-\sqrt2, \\
\end{align}
which matches the factorization you found
(roots at $x = -1+\sqrt2$ and $x = -1-\sqrt2$).